# Live updating view using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have question about live updating view using AngularJS. I would like add comment and live upadate view no reloading page. Now I am using `$route.reload()` is this good solution?. Second solution is fire function after add comment, below function working good, but always after add comment view scroll to bottom. Have you any advices to live update view? Comments are loading from mongodb

```
userFactory.readMoreCourse = function(id) {
    return $http.get('/api/product/' + id) 
}

function getComment() {
    User.readMoreCourse($routeParams.id).then(function(data){
        app.comment = data.data.product.comments 
    });
}    
getComment();
```

Comment: can you please explain a bit better what you mean? I didn't really understand it

Comment: If user add comment I would like  immediately update view, that I use $route.reload(), but I am nor sure that this is proper solution. Second solution what I used is above function, after add comment again load upadated comments from database. This work nice but my website scroll to bottom and I don't why this happen. I think $route.reload() i worst solution because view is blinking after fire this. So I try find best solution to update view for adding users comment

Comment: No, this is not the proper solution. In these cases you have two choices: polling or push notifications. Polling means that you call the server every x seconds and ask if there are new comments, if so, you get them and you display them. Push notifications means that the server sends back a message to the client, notifying something. In this case you need web sockets. I  hope it makes nice.

Comment: ok, thank you for answer and help :)

Comment: You're welcome and good coding :)

Comment: And last education question in your experience how many seconds or minutes is the best call to server?

Comment: It depends on the specific case of what you are doing. 
I would say that in general the best solution is to use a web socket if the updates are really frequent. I understand that this means more effort, but it's actually the best solution in terms of performances. When you make a request, most of the time is lost for the handshake of the connection. Every single request requires an handshake. 
Btw coming back to your question, if it's a social network and comments may happen every second, you should start a request at maximum every minute for providing a good UX.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **$interval** which Angular provides.

This will allow you to set a specific time in seconds that your function will trigger (as shown is 5 seconds).

You then want to push the data into your object so that the view will update automatically without refreshing etc.

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $interval) {
  var id = $routeParams.id;

  $scope.app = {
    comment: []
  };

  $scope.getComment = function() {
    User.readMoreCourse(id).then(function(response) {
      // Single result.
      $scope.app.comment.push(response.data);

      // Multiple results.
      angular.forEach(response.data, function(value, key) {
        $scope.app.comment.push(value);
      });
    });
  };

  $interval($scope.getComment, 5000);
});
```

This [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/jlB5YRN3BDA21A5J4c4M) will show you how this works in practice.